# My service doesn't get my mocked DbContext through its constructor

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, mocking, inversion-of-control

I try to create a fake db context to pass it to my service to test my functions from the service. The error i get is : Object reference not set to an instance of an object. This happens because my service doesn't get the new mocked context. I know this because watched it through debugger.

this is my unit test code :

```
        [TestMethod]
        public void VerifiesIfGetPersonByNameReturnsAValidPerson()
        {
            //Arrange
            var data = new List<Person>
            {
                new Person {Name = "Ana"},
                new Person {Name = "Marius"},
                new Person {Name = "George"},
            }.AsQueryable();

            var mockSet = new Mock<DbSet<Person>>();

            mockSet.As<IQueryable<Person>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(data.Provider);
            mockSet.As<IQueryable<Person>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(data.Expression);
            mockSet.As<IQueryable<Person>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(data.ElementType);
            mockSet.As<IQueryable<Person>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(data.GetEnumerator());

            var mockContext = new Mock<PersonDbContext>();
            mockContext.Setup(c => c.Persons).Returns(mockSet.Object);
            var service = new PersonService(mockContext.Object);
            var expected = "Marius";

            //Act
            var personDto = service.GetPersonByName("Marius");
            var actual = personDto.Name;

            //Assert
            Assert.AreEqual(expected,actual);
        }
```

And here is my service code :

```
public class PersonService : IPersonService
    {
        private PersonDbContext _db; 

        public PersonService(PersonDbContext db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }

    public PersonDto GetPersonByName(string name)
    {
        PersonDto personDto = Mapper.Map<PersonDto>(_db.Persons.Find(name));
        return personDto;
    }
...}
```

Why the service won't take the new context through its constructor ? Or what is the problem ? Why i keep getting null results when I execute the method GetPersonByName ?

Comment: I did the test following these examples : http://aikmeng.com/post/62817541825/how-to-mock-dbcontext-and-dbset-with-moq-for-unit and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn314429.aspx

Comment: Could you post the whole exception with call stack?

Comment: I changed it to use interfaces now, so it doesn't really matter anymore. I changed the code. I created a repository to hold my database. The problem was , I think, cause I used concrete classes. I should have used interfaces. Mock requires interfaces.

Comment: Anyway, thanks for trying to help...